# dynamically assign text to <a> from <li>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Using jquery 1.8.3

I am creating a function which creates an "li" element and sets some properties, including establishing an event listener.

```
$(this).closest('a').text(text); //$(this) is the li tag, and it does show that in the browser if you step through
```

The dom structure looks like this:

```
<div>
    <a></a>
    <div>
        <ul>...</ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

If you follow it in the debugger, both the .text() method and "text" variable are being populated with the correct info. There is something going on with the assignment part that I can't track. I am sure it is something stupid and obvious I am missing, but I could use some help getting over this hump.

If you need more info, please let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `anchor tag` is not the ancestor of the **li** .. Rather it is a **sibling of the div** in which it is encased..

You are looking for this I belive

```
$(this).closest('div').prev('a').text(text);
```

Comment: You beat me to it... here was my fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/7dU2G/ might as well not let it go to waste! =)

Comment: vyx.ca.. thanks for the fiddle .. @eoghtArmCode You are welcome

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `html()` function from jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#element li ").click(function(){
  $("#linki").html($(this).html());

  });
});



  <a href="" id="linki" ></a>

    <a></a>
    <div>
        <ul id="element">
          <li>Hello</li>

        </ul>
    </div>
```

live example http://jsbin.com/opoqid/46/edit